# While trying to automate a script using RIDE robot framework, delete text fields isn't working properly

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, ui-testing, robotframework-ide

I'm trying to delete the field as you see in the screenshot `initial value "-33"`using

```
SikuliLibrary.Press Special Key    DELETE
```

it delete "33" without no problem but even if I repeat the action of delete twice it don't delete "-" .

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by using `ctrl+a` in order to select the whole field to delete!